# Ayuda con un objeto tipo lista o modificar codigo para poder hacerlo funcionar

Tags: c#, poo

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual tengo que mostrar en pantalla cajas que entran a un inventario, lo que pasa es que de estas cajas tengo que mostrar algunos de sus datos que son que tipo de piezas contine, segun su fecha de entrada al inventario mostrar un numero para que indique que primero tiene que salir esa y ponerla de color rojo, mientras que las demas cajas estan en verde, y pues a mi lo que se me ocurrio fue hacer un objeto que guarde los dos la forma de ordenarla no la he implmentado pero es lo por que quiero hacer lo del fifo y lo de cambio de colores primero.

Por ejemplo si se manejan 4 piezas distintas, a, b, c y d entonces todas las cajas que tengan piezas de a deben mostrar cantidad de piezas que contienen, y el orden en el que deben ser retiradas segun la fecha, ademas de la que debe salir primero pintarse de color rojo, y asi con cada uno de los tipos b, c y d

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente pero no me funciona por que siento que el objeto lo tengo mal hecho o no estoy haciendo algo bien:

Este es el constructor de las cajas

```
class cajas
    {
        public string partNumber;
        public int fifo;
        public DateTime fecha;
        public int quantity;
        public int position;
        public int orderColumn;
        public string color;
        public int boxnum;

        public cajas(string partNumber, int fifo, int quantity,int position,DateTime fecha,int orderColumn, string color, int boxnum)
        {
            this.partNumber = partNumber;
            this.fifo = fifo;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.position = position;
            this.fecha = fecha;
            this.orderColumn = orderColumn;
            this.color = color;
            this.boxnum = boxnum;

        }

    }
```

Y esta es la parte de intento de hacer que funcione

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int order = 0;
        List<cajas> caja = new List<cajas>();
        string cad = "";
        bool cachado = false;
        int comp = 0;
        DateTime aux = DateTime.MaxValue;
        string auxpart = "";
        int c = -10;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 100;
        string color2 = "Green";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startTimer();
        }

        private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            order++;
            a++;
            b++;
            caja.Add(new cajas("10-qt", 120, 110, 2,DateTime.Now,order,"Green",b));
            caja.Add( new cajas("10-sag",10,110,1,DateTime.Now,order,"Green",a));

        }
        private void startTimer()
        {
            timer1.Start();
            timer1.Interval = 500;
        }

        public void comparador(DateTime d1, DateTime d2, string partNum, string partNum2,int boxnum)
        {

            foreach (cajas acaja in caja)
            {

                if (acaja.boxnum == boxnum)
                {
                    if (partNum == partNum2)
                    {

                        DateTime.Compare(d1, d2);
                        if (c < 0)
                        {
                            acaja.color = "Red";
                        }
                        else if (c == 0)
                        {
                            acaja.color = "Green";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            acaja.color = "Green";
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = aux.ToString();
            label2.Text = auxpart;

            foreach (cajas acaja in caja)
            {
                switch (acaja.position)
                {
                    case 1:
                        switch (acaja.orderColumn)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                button1.Text = acaja.partNumber + "\n" + acaja.quantity + "\n" + acaja.fecha;
                                comparador(acaja.fecha, aux, acaja.partNumber, auxpart,acaja.boxnum);
                                button1.BackColor = Color.FromName(acaja.color);
                                aux = acaja.fecha;
                                auxpart = acaja.partNumber;

                                break;
                            case 2:
                                button5.Text = acaja.partNumber + "\n" + acaja.quantity + "\n" + acaja.fecha;
                                comparador(acaja.fecha, aux, acaja.partNumber, auxpart,acaja.boxnum);
                                button5.BackColor = Color.FromName(acaja.color);
                                aux = acaja.fecha;

                                auxpart = acaja.partNumber;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                button9.Text = acaja.partNumber + "\n" + acaja.quantity + "\n" + acaja.fecha;
                                comparador(acaja.fecha, aux, acaja.partNumber, auxpart, acaja.boxnum);
                                button9.BackColor = Color.FromName(acaja.color);
                                aux = acaja.fecha;
                                auxpart = acaja.partNumber;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                button13.Text = acaja.partNumber + "\n" + acaja.quantity + "\n" + acaja.fecha;
                                comparador(acaja.fecha, aux, acaja.partNumber, auxpart, acaja.boxnum);
                                button13.BackColor = Color.FromName(acaja.color);
                                aux = acaja.fecha;
                                auxpart = acaja.partNumber;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (button2.Text == "")
                        {
                            button2.Text = acaja.fifo.ToString();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

El comparador no me funciona puesto que despues de comparar la primera ya todas las pinta de rojo

Comment: Una cosa, inicializas c a -10 y ya no varías su valor, con lo cual siempre va a pintar de rojo las cajas. Si c tiene que tener el valor del resultado de comparación de fechas, tienes que hacer c = DateTime.Compare(d1,d2);

Comment: Tienes razon no se en que momento borre esa parte y ya no me fije gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar yo quitaría el campo `color` de la clase que define la caja, ya que el color de la caja no depende de las propiedades de ésta, si no de la posición que ocupa en una colección de cajas.

```
class Caja
{
    public string partNumber;
    public int fifo;
    public DateTime fecha;
    public int quantity;
    public int position;
    public int orderColumn;
    public int boxnum;

    public Caja(string partNumber, int fifo, int quantity, int position, DateTime fecha, int orderColumn, int boxnum)
    {
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
        this.fifo = fifo;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.position = position;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.orderColumn = orderColumn;
        this.boxnum = boxnum;
    }
}
```

Luego podrías crearte una clase `CajaCollection` que sea una lista de cajas y que tenga un método para obtener el color de una caja particular:

```
class CajaCollection : List<Caja>
{

    public Color ObtenerColorCaja(Caja caja)
    {
        return ObtenerColorCaja(IndexOf(caja));
    }

    public Color ObtenerColorCaja(int index)
    {
        // Localiza la primera caja ordenando por fecha y con el mismo partNumber
        var primeraCaja = this.OrderBy(c => c.fecha)
            .First(c => c.partNumber == this[index].partNumber);

        // Si el índice coincide es la primera a salir (rojo), si no verde
        return index == IndexOf(primeraCaja) ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Así no tendrías más que definir la lista de cajas como un objeto `CajaCollection`:

```
CajaCollection caja = new CajaCollection();
```

y para obtener el color de una caja concreta podrías llamar a alguna de las sobrecargas del método `ObtenerColorCaja`:

```
button5.BackColor = caja.ObtenerColorCaja(acaja);
```

Comment: me gusto esta forma de verlo intentare utilizarlo asi gracias

Comment: oye perdon pero me quede estancado intentando que el fifo me muestre el orden segun la fecha y no logro retornarlo, me podrias dar una sugerencia??

Comment: Es complicado sin ver el código. Lo mejor para no mezclar temas sería que abrieses otra pregunta con tu código, para ver hasta dónde has llegado y dónde tienes el problema.

Comment: quiza sea pedir mucho pero si me puedes ayudar ya formule la pregunta es esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137190/ayuda-con-codigo-para-obtener-numero-segun-antig%C3%BCedad-del-objeto-por-medio-de-un/137198?noredirect=1#comment256285_137198 me lo diferon para hacer por medio de un foreach pero se me hace mejor como tu me lo sujeriste de utilizar una sobre carga ya que la solucion que me dieron se me dificulta filtrar el numero de parte y separar la numeracion y sea independiente por numero de parte