# Ayuda con codigo para obtener numero segun Antigüedad del objeto por medio de un metodo

Tags: c#, poo, lista

La cuestion es la siguiente tengo un objeto al cual le asigno algunos valores entre ellos la fecha y son ordenados por fecha y si es el por asi decirlo mas viejo dentro de la lista se pinta de color rojo, lo que quiero ahora es que segun el orden por fecha tambien se les asigne un numero del 1 al n cajas que tengo y poderlo poner en pantalla al imprimir el objeto y asi tener el orden en el que deben ser retirados.

En resumen quiero que me muestre segun la fecha cual debe salir primero enumerado con el numero 1, el que siga de este tenga el 2 y el ultimo el numero n.

El codigo del objeto es el siguiente:

```
class Caja
{
    public string partNumber;
    public int fifo;
    public DateTime fecha;
    public int quantity;
    public int position;
    public int orderColumn;
    public int boxnum;

    public Caja(string partNumber, int fifo, int quantity, int position, DateTime fecha, int orderColumn, int boxnum)
    {
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
        this.fifo = fifo;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.position = position;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.orderColumn = orderColumn;
        this.boxnum = boxnum;
    }
}
```

Y el del metodo es el siguiente no esta terminada la parte del fifo por que no se como plantearla les pido ayuda.

```
 class CajaCollection : List<Caja>
    {

        public Color ObtenerColorCaja(Caja caja)
        {
            return ObtenerColorCaja(IndexOf(caja));
        }

        public Color ObtenerColorCaja(int index)
        {
            // Localiza la primera caja ordenando por fecha y con el mismo partNumber
            var primeraCaja = this.OrderBy(c => c.fecha)
                .First(c => c.partNumber == this[index].partNumber);

            // Si el índice coincide es la primera a salir (rojo), si no verde
            return index == IndexOf(primeraCaja) ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
        }
        public  int ObtenerFifoCaja(Caja caja)
        {
            return ObtenerFifoCaja(IndexOf(caja));
        }
        public int ObtenerFifiCaja(int index)
        {
            var primeraCaja = this.OrderBy(c => c.fecha)
                 .First(c => c.partNumber == this[index].partNumber);
            return index == IndexOf(primeraCaja);
        }
    }
```

El objeto tiene una caracteristica que se llama fifo pero era por que la queria hacer de otra forma pero no la logre hacer funcionar y se me hace mas facil hacer funcionarla con este metodo.

Comment: FIFO? first in first out? que tiene que ver con todo lo que describiste? (que no esta muy claro). Vuelve a leer la pregunta, y deja en claro el problema, que estas viendo, y que es lo que esperas ver.

Comment: @gbianchi ya lo explique un poco mejor a ver si asi se comprende

Comment: Un poco mejor, pero de fifo no tiene nada. Saca eso porque confunde. Que le pasa al linq de order? No ordena?

Comment: @gbianchi pues es fifo por que la fecha del objeto que entra primero debe salir primero y estar numerado con un 1 y asi con los siguientes, si ordena lo que no se como hacer es asignarles ese numero de primero entra primero sale

Comment: Creo que con fifo no tiene que ver y según entiendo quieres poner un número 1 a la fecha más antigua e ir enumerando conforme avance la fecha?

Comment: si eso exactamente quiero hacer por medio del metodo pero no se como hacerlo asignarle el numero despues de ordenarlos @5frags

Comment: Bueno tenes varias opciones. y no es fifo! pq si cargo primero una fecha y despues otra posterior y despues otra anterior vas a tener que ordenarlo todo. Nada que ver con FIFO, que es una lista donde lo primero que entra es lo primero que sale sin ninguna clase de orden!. ahora, podes agregar una variable orden a la clase y enumerar los items una vez que esten cargados y agregar el numero de orden ahi.

Comment: Al parecer está mal planteado tu problema, por que fifo no es, fifo es el que primero llega primero lo atienden, lo que quieres hacer es ordenarlos por fecha y con esa fecha ir sacándolos de la cola.

Comment: Pues en realidad no tiene orden esto, el orden se lo doy por el metodo para obtener la entrada mas vieja y marcarla de color rojo y sobre lo otro no se como hacerlo como numerarlos... @gbianchi

Comment: @5frags si eso quiero ya olvidemos el fifo pues solo quiero marcarlos con ese numero segun su Antigüedad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enumerar una lista, basta con hacer lo siguiente:

Se deberia agregar a la clase Caja una propiedad (variable) a la cual llamare orden.

Teniendo definida la lista como:

```
CajaCollection objCajaCollection;
....

//defino la posicion
int i = 0; //o 1, como lo quieras hacer
foreach(var p in objCajaCollection.OrderBy(c => c.fecha))
{
    p.orden = i;
    i++;
}
```

Esto te va a dejar el numero de orden en la lista.. despues para recorrerla por ese orden podes hacer:

```
foreach(var p in objCajaCollection.OrderBy(c => c.orden))
```

Comment: lo utilice pero no deja de aumentar el numero

Comment: a que te referis con que no deja de aumentar el numero?

Comment: el numero aumenta infinitamente solo empieza en 1 y de ahi se va sumando pero para la misma caja

Comment: no puede ser eso.. este codigo recorre el objeto que tiene tus cajas y le asigna un orden a cada una. que objeto estas recorriendo vos?

Comment: ok ya lo hice era error mio perdon lo estaba recorriendo en un timer que es el que actualiza la vista si ya funciona gracias

Comment: lo que pasa es que de esta forma llevo control solo de la fecha pero quiero poder tener este orden tambien separandolo por la caracteristica partNumber, segun el partNumber tener un conteo de 1 a n y tener n part num tambien no se si me doy a entender

Comment: No, no te entiendo, pero podes abrir una pregunta nueva si queres. Igual si esto es un ejercicio, deberias intentarlo por voa mismo, y despues explicar donde te estas trabando